Accessing Images in media/ folder In Django, as public url
I can access the image on the local machine as
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/taj.jpg
in the browser.
How can I access the same image publicly in the browser?
Like url: http://49.128.160.80:8000/media/taj.jpg

is the second URL your IPv4 address?

in production too, are you storing your media files in local/django's filesystem ?

@user70 Yes, it is IPv4 address.

@HujaakbarThese images would be dynamically generated. Could you guide me on where else to store them?
